# C# Xml User Control Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I serializing my User control and it doesn't work.
I serializing with XmlWriter. When I serialize my user control I got:

```
<tmc:WebPage_Control Width=\"600\" Height=\"400\" Canvas.Left=\"251.798397863818\" Canvas.Top=\"122.88785046729\" Panel.ZIndex=\"1\">
        <Border BorderThickness=\"1,1,1,1\" BorderBrush=\"#FF000000\" Background=\"#FFFFFFFF\">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\" Height=\"30\" VerticalAlignment=\"Top\">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=\"0.5,0\" EndPoint=\"0.5,1\">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStop Color=\"#FFE2E2E2\" Offset=\"0\" />
                                <GradientStop Color=\"#FFFFFFFF\" Offset=\"1\" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                    <Button Width=\"24\" Margin=\"3,3,3,3\" Visibility=\"Collapsed\">
                        <Image Source=\"pack://application:,,,/app;component/Resources/Specific/Undo.png\" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button Width=\"24\" Margin=\"3,3,3,3\" Visibility=\"Collapsed\">
                        <Image Source=\"pack://application:,,,/app;component/Resources/Specific/Redo.png\" />
                    </Button>
                    <Label VerticalContentAlignment=\"Center\">URL</Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <WindowsFormsHost x:Name=\"FormHost\" Child=\"{x:Null}\" Margin=\"0,30,0,0\" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
</tmc:WebPage_Control>
```

And I want something like others controls:

```
 <tmc:WebPage_Control Width=\"600\" Height=\"400\" Canvas.Left=\"251.798397863818\" Canvas.Top=\"122.88785046729\" Panel.ZIndex=\"1\"/>
```

When I deserialize my xml output, it not work properly.
My UserControl have custom dependencyproperty. My user control:

```
<Button Margin="3" Width="24" Visibility="{Binding Path=BackForwardVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Click="Undo_Click">
         <Image Source="/app;component/Resources/Specific/Undo.png" /> 
 </Button>
```

So when I deserialize it not working to change Binding BackForwardVisibility from code because I got:

```
<Button Width=\"24\" Margin=\"3,3,3,3\" Visibility=\"Collapsed\">
     <Image Source=\"pack://application:,,,/app;component/Resources/Specific/Undo.png\" />
</Button>
```

My Class

```
 public partial class WebPage_Control : UserControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BFVisibilityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackForwardVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(WebPage_Control), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));


        public Visibility BackForwardVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(BFVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BFVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser;


        public WebPage_Control()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Debug.WriteLine("Initialized!");


                System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webbr = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            webBrowser = webbr;
            webbr.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webbr.Navigated += Webbr_Navigated;
            FormHost.Child = webbr;
        }


...
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  As it is we have no way of telling what you did or what went wrong - or even if you are serializing a winforms or WPF control, or something else.  Your desired XML isn't even valid either since a namespace corresponding to the `tmc:` prefix is never even defined.  I'd also suggest checking [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions on how to write a question that is likely to get answered here.

Comment: Where are your classes?  If it is not working the the classes do not match the xml.

Comment: Edited question. Thanks